# how to separate words in arguments (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'say') {
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`Please tell the bot what to say, ${message.author}`);
        }
    
        const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${args}`)
            .setColor('RED')
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
})
```

but whenever i type `!say subscribe today` it comes out as `subscribe,today`
can someone please tell me a way to separate the argument so the commas arent there and its more than one word?

Comment: args is an array of strings, you can create a string from it using for example `text = args.join(' ');`

Comment: where would i put this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (command === 'say') {
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`Please tell the bot what to say, ${message.author}`);
        }
        let text = args.join(' '); //Join the array of strings with a space to create a text to send
        const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(text)
            .setColor('RED')
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
```

More on array.join() method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '!';
client.on('message', (message) => {
    let args = message.content.substring(0, prefix.length).split(' ');
    let command = args.shift();
});
```

Comment: im confused i dont understand how this helps

Comment: args its command arguments, command its first written world